# How to add checkbox control at the Header of DatagridviewCheckBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, controls

Can anyone please provide the C# coding to add checkbox control at the Header of DatagridviewCheckBoxColumn.

Comment: Hi, could you clarify if this is indeed for the datagridview in winforms? And also, to you want the checkbox in the header row, perhaps beside the text, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Check Box Column to a template field. Then add the Check box to the header template.

Comment: datagridview doesnt have property called as headerRow

Comment: good point, I was thinking of footer row, in that case, Microprocessor has a better answer

Answer (score -2):

I think WarithNath is right.
Here is a suggestion code.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
   </EditItemTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   <HeaderTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxToSelectAll" runat="server" />
   </HeaderTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
```

Hope it works!

Comment: This answer is for the asp.net GridView control, not the winforms datagridview